# Is this an acceptable way to determine EOF while reading a file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, null, feof, fgetc

I am fairly new to PHP and just trying to convert something I did in C.  The idiom for reading from a file in C that I was taught was:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    doSomethingWith(c);
}
```

I've done some reading and it would seem that the 'right' way to do this in PHP is:

```
while (!feof($file)) {
    $c = fgetc($file);
    doSomethingWith($c);
}
```

My question is: Is it ok to combine the two as follows (I have tried it, and its working ok on my test file), or are there situations where this could find a null before EOF?:

```
while (($c = fgets($f)) != null) {
    doSomethingWith($c);
}
```

Cheers in advance

Steve

Comment: *(tip)* [Iterating file contents with Spl](http://gooh.posterous.com/iterating-files-with-spl)

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  Is using that SPL method more PHP-correct?  (If this was Python I'd say, "Is this more Pythonic?" - not sure if that translates to PHP... Python people sometimes seem like they have a carrot stuck somewhere when it comes to how things should be done and doing things Pythonically :)

Comment: No. You can use both. I just find the SPL way more convenient, versatile and readable. But that's just me. Use what suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok, but the way you are doing it it's wrong (at least "not correct at all"). [`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets) returns `false`, if the end of the file is reached, thus you should test against `false` instead. It works for you, because you use the "simple" equality operator (`==`), that will case `null` to `false`, when comparing against a boolean.

> Returns a string of up to length - 1 bytes read from the file pointed to by handle. If there is no more data to read in the file pointer, then FALSE is returned.
>
> If an error occurs, FALSE is returned.

This means, it have to look like

```
while (($c = fgets($f)) !== false) {
    doSomethingWith($c);
}
```

Comment: Ah, appreciate the edit... I'll look up the different equality operators and make better use of documentation.  If it returns false, then could I have just done "while($c = fgets($f))"?  Cheers, Steve

Comment: Maybe. In this context, I wouldn't suggest it, because this will cast everything else to a boolean too (its identical to `($c = fgets($f)) == true)`), which means, that `0` and `""` will result in `false`. Here `fgets()` should always return the newline-character too, thus it _should_ work, but I wouldn't rely on it ;)

Comment: I just read the documentation - and apparently I can't do as I suggested in the above comment as a "0" or "" _MAY_ equate to a false... so I will stick with the boolean equality operator.  Thanks again, you and Jon got me pointed in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` is documented to return `false` when there is no more data to read. Therefore, the technically correct solution would be

```
// Notice the !== [non-identical] operator below
while (($c = fgets($f)) !== false) {
    doSomethingWith($c);
}
```

This is better because `fgets` could legitimately return an empty (zero-length) string, which would compare equal to `null` when using the equality operator. The operator `!==` also checks the *type* of its operands, so this way you are covered.